I am getting a RecaptchaAction error when trying to authenticate a user in my android app through android studio
I am trying to implement firebase authentication into my app but I keeping getting an error about a Recaptcha Action failing
The code of the function for this, which is connected to a button through an onClick function is
public void createAccount(View v)
    {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("hitherenoyou123@gmail.com", "password123#")
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("hi", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Account Successful.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w("hi", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

and when I click the button, it calls the function and tells me the authentication fails and in my log cat, I get an error saying
nitial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signUpPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ socket failed:EPERM (Operation not permitted) ]
followed by a warning saying
createUserWithEmail:failure                                                                                                     com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ socket failed:EPERM (Operation not permitted) ]
and I have tried redownloading my google services json file but that hasn't fixed anything and I can't find any solutions online so I'm hoping someone can help me

I was in a similar situation getting this error with the RecaptchaAction error.
My error being

Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signUpPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]

I fixed this error by enabling Email/Password sign in within Firebase Authentication Sign-in method. Note that the password sent to Firebase has to be at least 6 characters long.
Check and make sure that you're enabled your sign-in method within firebase.
